# Reduce method in java

Tags: java, methods

I have 2 methods almost use the same logic. one method uses an extra rangeKey condition .

I want to extract the rangeCondition and reuse the remaining logic . How I can do?

I want to keep common logic in one place and ConditionExpression in other

But I am not getting the proper efficient reduced code

Method 1:

```java
public List<CustomItem> queryOnRStartDateAsSecondaryIndex(@NonNull final Long rStartDate) {
    log.info("Getting record from CustomItem Table based on Review StartDate {}", rStartDate);
    final CustomItem reviewStartDateGSIKey = CustomItem.builder()   
        .reviewStartDate(rStartDate)
        .build();
    final DynamoDBQueryExpression<CustomItem> dynamoDBQueryExpression = DynamoDBUtil.getGSIDynamoDBQueryExpression(reviewStartDateGSIKey, REVIEW_START_DATE_INDEX);
    try {
        return dynamoDBMapper
            .query(CustomItem.class, dynamoDBQueryExpression);
    }
    catch (DynamoDBMappingException | AmazonClientException e) {
        String msg = String.format("Error while getting record for Review Start Date: %s " + "from CustomItem Table", rStartDate);
        throw handleDDBExceptions(msg, e);
    }   
}
```

Method 2:

```java
public List<CustomItem> queryOnRStartDateAsSecondaryIndex(@NonNull final Long rStartDate, @NonNull final Long startTime, @NonNull final Long endTime) {
    log.info("Getting record from Table based on reviewStartDate {}, reviewStartTime between {} and {}", rStartDate, startTime, endTime);
    final CustomItem reviewStartDateGSIKey = CustomItem.builder()
        .reviewStartDate(rStartDate)
        .build();
    final DynamoDBQueryExpression<CustomItem> dynamoDBQueryExpression = DynamoDBUtil.getGSIDynamoDBQueryExpression(reviewStartDateGSIKey, REVIEW_START_DATE_INDEX);
    Condition rangeKeyCondition = DynamoDBUtil.getDynamoDBQueryCondition(ComparisonOperator.BETWEEN, startTime, endTime);
    Map<String, Condition> rangeKeyConditionMap = new HashMap<>();
    rangeKeyConditionMap.put(REVIEW_START_TIME, rangeKeyCondition);
    dynamoDBQueryExpression.setRangeKeyConditions(rangeKeyConditionMap);
    try {
        return dynamoDBMapper.query(CustomItem.class, dynamoDBQueryExpression);
    }
    catch (DynamoDBMappingException | AmazonClientException e) {
        String msg = String.format("Error while getting record for revie Start Date: %s " + "from CustomItem Table", rStartDate);
        throw handleDDBExceptions(msg, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please: you want other humans to spend their free time to help you with your problem. So ensure to make that easy as possible. Starting with: nicely formatted code. Dont throw something at us that has so many useless newlines. And then: consider to *not* put `final` on everything. To a certain degree, this is just "line noise".

Comment: Also note: asking about reviewing and improving working code isn't in scope of this community. You might want to carefully study the help center at https://codereview.stackexchange.com to decide whether that place would be a better fit for your request.

Comment: Where, one solution could be: have a private helper method that takes that `rangeKeyCondition` as argument ... but knows how to deal with the condition being null for example. Then your first method calls the helper method with null, and the second method calls it with a non-null condition.